# How to get notified if the user updated the app right after the app update?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-automotive

The main goal is to get notified about the app getting updated and restart a service after app update.

Having a BroadcastReceiver and listening to `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`  to start my service when the app gets updated. And I get the following error

```
BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.volvocars.dj flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.volvocars.drivingjournal/.core.service.KeepTheAppAliveReceiver
```

At the first glance, It seems like one of [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts),

And I found that I could replace `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` by `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` the result is that the error goes away but the BroadcastReceiver **doesn't get any update event** and it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s broadcast receiver class `ClassChild.java` has this `intent-filter`:

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".subdir.ClassChild"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/foo>
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

and if let's say the `ClassChild` may extends `classParent`, let`ClassChild` override `classParent`'s `onReceive()`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

And `classParent.java`'s `onReceive()` can share by child to check the broadcast (you don't put funny thing such as `final onReceive()` which causes child not able to override):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent == null) {
        return;
    }
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(action)) {
        ... do your stuff
    }
```

Finally, you can test app update with command `adb install -r -d <your.apk>` if you worry Android Studio may not send `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast. (`-r` means re-install and keeping its data, `-d` means allow version downgrade)